# Importing project from Eclipse to Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse

I just imported an Android project(which was written in Eclipse) to Android Studio. At first, I had some problems so I deleted some dependencies and later when I reimported the project to Android Studio
I had to include the dependencies which I earlier deleted. I tried to run the app and I got the following messages.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
Manifest merger failed : Attribute activity#com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity@configChanges value=(keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale) from AndroidManifest.xml
is also present at [com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:9.4.0] AndroidManifest.xml value=(keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:configChanges"' to <activity> element at AndroidManifest.xml to override.

Error:orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize)

Error:orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale) from AndroidManifest.xml
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try `Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:configChanges"' to <activity> element`?

Comment: Yes and I got again a Manifest merger error